# Ubuntu 23.10 boot error: [FAILED] Failed to start gpu-manager.service - Detect the available GPUs and deal with any systen changes

Tags: boot, gpu, gpu-driver, 23.10

This is the error I get at the start of the ubuntu and I saw the similar errors like you change lightdm package or config or you should update your grub, none of them work for me.

Some people say its the graphic card driver error, you should update it, and I have really old graphic card ATI Radeon 5550